# Give look behind the priority over the actual regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I am looking for a regular expression that can strip all 'a' characters from the beginning of an input word (comprising only of English alphabet).

How would I do this using an regular expression?

The following look behind based regex fails to do the job:

`(?<=a*?)(\w)+`

as for input `abc` the above regular expression would return `abc`.

Is there a clean way to do this using lookbehinds?

A (brute force-ish) regular expression that does work is using negation:

`(?<=a*)([[^a]&&\w])*`

which returns the correct answer of `bc` for an input word `abc`.

But I was wondering if there could be a more elegant regular expression, say, using the correct [quantifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html)?

Comment: Sorry it is unclear why do you need a lookbehind for removing `a` from input

Comment: do you want to replace all `a's`?

Comment: I think you are looking to remove any `a` that is not a standalone word. Use `.replaceAll("a\\B|\\Ba", "")` then. See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/qN3nL5/1).

Comment: Should `bac` return `bc` or `bac`?

Comment: If it should return `bac`, then [`strip()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_strip.htm) would do the job.

Comment: @anubhava: the question is more of an educational pursuit rather than an application one. It is intended to help me understand the nuances of look-behinds and quantifiers.

Comment: @rock321987: Thanks for the correction. No, I intend to remove the a's only at the beginning of the word. So, the result of the application of the regular expression must never begin with an 'a'. I've made the appropriate correction in the question.

Comment: @KennyLau `bac` should return `bac`

Comment: To replace `a` from starting of a word use `String repl = str.replaceFirst("^a+\\B", "");`

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern removeWords = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:a)\\b\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher fix = removeWords.matcher(YourWord);
String fixedString = fix.replaceAll("");
```

this will remove **`a`** from the current string and if you want to remove some other letters

```
Pattern removeWords = Pattern.compile("\\b(?:a|b|c)\\b\\s*",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

you ca do it this way

Answer (score 0):

I think that a regex for this problem is overkill.

You could instead do:

```
str = str.startsWith("a") ? str.substring(1) : str;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are much more simpler way to do this, but as you insist on using using lookbehinds, I will give one. The regex will be

```
(?<=\b)a+(\w*)
```

*Regex Breakdown*

```
(?<=\b) #Find all word boundaries
a+ #Match the character a literally at least once. We have already ensured using word boundary to find those a's only which are starting of word
(\w*) #Find remaining characters
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/sR0lP2/2)**

*Java Code*

```
String str = "abc cdavbvhsza aaabcd";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=\\b)a+(\\w*)", "$1"));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/IuR5Fw)**

Comment: My bad. I intended to replace all 'a's from the beginning not just one. I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @RockyInde lookbehinds should always be of fixed length..though JAVA allows it due to some bug..

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I do agree there is something fishy regarding the quantifier specification in Java's look behinds.

However, your regex would fail to strip the beginning a's as you have expressed them outside the lookbehind. `abc` returns `abc` for your regex.

Comment: what about the words that do not start with an 'a'? The regex should return the word itself in such cases.

Comment: @RockyInde It is doing all you want..please check the **[link](http://ideone.com/Umoexq)**

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
(?i)\\ba?(\\w+)\\b
```

and replace a word with captured `group 1`.
Code example:

```
String word = "aWord Another";
word = word.replaceAll("(?i)\\ba?(\\w+)\\b", "$1");
System.out.println(word);
```

with output:

```
Word nother
```